# Regex to fetch value from string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

can you help me out to fetch some value from this string which is below

```
ldn2spc2.ebrd.comDiskUtilization-D(Disk) --> Disk Utilization 100 > 95
%(threshold)
```

I want to fetch the drive letter which before "*Disk*" in this case which is 'D'.

I have tried this regex

```
ebrd.comDiskUtilization-(\D*)\ --
```

which give `D(Disk)` but my requirement is to fetch only drive letter.
Please help.

Comment: In which environment do you run your RegExp?

Also see non-capturing groups

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern you are capturing in group 1 `(\D*)` matching 0+ times not a digit  followed by a space and 2 dashes `\ --`.

Using `\D` will also match `(Disk)` as it does not contain a digit.

Note that you don't have to escape the space using a backslash and you do have to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
ebrd\.comDiskUtilization-([A-Z])\([^)]+\) --
```

In parts

- `ebrd\.comDiskUtilization-` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `)` Close group
- `\([^)]+\)` Match from an opening till a closing parenthesis using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `--` Match a space and `--`

The drive letter will be in capturing group 1.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hmt5UZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends much by the RegEx engine you are using. Unfortunately sometimes it is not easy to know it.

I tested your text with the engine of **PCRE 8.41 2017-07-05** and I get the 'D' with the regex:

```
((\w+[\.-])+)\K\w(?=\(Disk\))
```

But it does not work for example with **Chrome's Javascript**. For this instead I can use this:

```
(?<=(\w+[\.-])+)\w(?=\(Disk\))
```

Try them both and see which one works for you.

Comment: Glad I helped! If you confirm it worked can you approve my answer? :)
Also, which one of the two worked?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using Javascript.  If my understanding is correct, this regex will only capture the drive letter as capture group 1:

ebrd.comDiskUtilization-([A-Za-z])\D*\ --

With that said, I tend to think Sterconium's solution is a better, more elegant solution.  If you need the drive letter to be a capture group, you could put parenthesis around the \w - in which case it would be capture group 2.